# Where to download Eclipse WTP

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, installation, eclipse-luna

Hello everyone. I have current Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 up and running and now I want to have option to run->run on server on Tomcat also installed and tested.

As I understood I must install WTP so I searched and ended up on this page:

[image]

The page is 1 week old. I understand they probably want the page to be IE6 optimized, but this one looks like from 1989. Moreover, they are like 30 links on the page with acronyms like cat running on a keyboard.

So can anyone tell me how to install WTP for Eclipse Luna 4.4.1

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Help->Eclipse Market Place

and search for WTP and install it.

[image]

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Full instructions are at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F . Short answer: get the Java EE IDE from http://download.eclipse.org (the latest proper release should be shown by default).